# Why either Google chrome or Microsoft Edge keeps lagging when I run them simultaneously?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

I am wondering why Edge and Chrome are slow even on scroll when I am running them both but the performance of either drastically improves when I kill one application and let the one run. Could it be because of the two applications using the same rendering engine could be the one causing the overkill on my system?

Comment: I am not seeing that here. Maybe related to the number of open tabs in both?  Suggestion:  Uninstall Chrome, restart, repair Edge (reinstalls Edge), restart and install Chrome again.

Comment: Edge came with a recent windows update, I never installed it, windows forced it on me. Chrome used to work fine before the update, should I roll back out of the updates?

Comment: Both Chrome and Edge are fully updated here.

Comment: "Could it be because of the two applications using the same rendering engine could be the one causing the overkill on my system?" - No

Comment: @John, yeah they are fully updated, do they use same rendering Chromium engine? could be the reason why, when i run firefox alongside chrome I run as many tabs and I do not get slow application performance

Comment: They use the same rendering engine but I keep my tabs low (just a couple).

Comment: Try running them both in Incognito mode, where extensions are disabled. If they now speed up, then the problem with one of your extensions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are other browsers slow, e.g., Firefox, if run  along with Chrome or (Chrome-based) Edge? If not, it might point to both Chrome-based browsers sharing a resource.

Comment: @harrymc, could be, I have an adblock and then Edge stole everything from Chrome:-History, Extensions, Bookmarks. I wasn't even asked for approval, could be the reason why. Lemme try to disable the extensions

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, and that resource could be my hard drive which has all along been bottlenecking my system, my RAM is fine though its 8 gigs DDR4

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU, I think you've identified the cause of the issue. Browsers cache pages, and if memory is short, the OS caches memory to disk, 1,000 times or so slower than RAM. Firefox has a number of tools to reduce cache size, or eliminate chaching completely, and likely Chrome and Edge do, as well. https://www.davidtan.org/tips-reduce-firefox-memory-cache-usage/